# Weather API not getting data from other locations

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

**I am creating a weather app in django and i want the users to be able to search for weather on any 
  locations using the API...i have tried multiple times to use the HTML input but it's not working

def home(request):

```
    choose_city = "London" #selected city
    url = f"https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q= 
    {choose_city}&units=imperial&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22" #open weather url
    response = requests.get(url)
    get_weather = response.json() 



    for weather in get_weather["weather"]:
        pass

    temperature =  get_weather["main"]
    city_name = get_weather["name"]





    weatherContext = {

    "main" : weather["main"],
    "description": weather["description"],
    "temp": temperature,
    "city_name": city_name,
    "city": choose_city,
    "url": url

    }
    return render(request, "MyWeather/base.html", weatherContext)


here is the HTML
```

> Blockquote

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">


      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" id="nav">
      <form class="form-inline" action={{url}}>

        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" >
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search </button>
      </form>
    </nav>
    <br>


    <div>
      <h2>
        City: {{city_name}}
      </h2>
    </div><br><br>

      <h4>Weather:     {{main}}</h4><br><hr>
      <h4> Description:     {{description}}</h4><br><hr>

    {% for temperature, key in temp.items%}
      {%if temperature == "temp"%}
         <h4>Temperature:   {{key}} °F</h4><br><hr>

      {%endif%}

     {%endfor%}
```

How can i be able to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Here's a problem in your code:

```
 for weather in get_weather["weather"]:
    pass
```

it is actually doing nothing.
As I tried the api, there's a list of weather. so you can try the first element of the "weather"

```
weather = get_weather["weather"][0] #it will get the first element always
```

Code above can raise error if there's no element in the variable.
so try not to raise any error:

```
if get_weather["weather"]:  # if found any data
   weather = get_weather["weather"][0]
else:
   weather = {}
```

Comment: ok thanks, but the problem i am having is how to search for any city with the HTML input through the API using django

Comment: You can create a form with input of city and on submit run this view function (by url) with request.GET. You can get the data by adding "name" attribute in input field.